# In unix script, SQL script output to a file and if any sql error to an error file

Tags: oracle, unix

I am trying to do the below

> in shell script, call an .sql script which extracts to a file
>   in case of any error in .sql script, it should re-direct error to error file

```
sqlplus -s $orcl_user/$ocle_auth@$db_orcl < $/path/extract.sql >> $path/abc.dat;
```

Now how do i re-direct the error of extract.sql to a file by name error.log

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sqlplus -s $orcl_user/$ocle_auth@$db_orcl < $/path/extract.sql 1>> $path/abc.dat 2> error.log;`

stdout (normal program output) can be redirected using `1>` or `1>>` to append, while stderr can be redirected using `2>` or `2>>` to append. You can redirect both to a single file by using `&>` or `&>>` to append. Not specifying which output you are redirecting with `>` or `>>` has it default to stdout.

Comment: Thanks but this did not output the error in .sql script to error.log file. Instead, the error was shown in the abc.dat file..

Comment: That suggests that the error from your SQL script is not transmitted from your `sqlplus` program as stderr, but rather stdout. You will have to do some extra scripting to capture the stdout to a variable and test the contents of that variable to see if they match some pattern that you define to determine if it's an error or not. That's probably beyond the scope of an SO question though.